# How to export a MySQL database to json using mysql-connector from PYTHON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I want to export a mysql database with one table to json using the libraries `mysql-connector` and `json` from python.

**What I tried:**

```py
import mysql-connector, json

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM records")
data=cursor.fetchall()
for e in data:
  print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

**Traceback error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bsentor.py", line 238, in <module>
    print(json.dumps(data))
  File "C:\Users\Justo Gregorio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Justo Gregorio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Justo Gregorio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Justo Gregorio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: How far have you gotten with this? What errors are you experiencing?

Comment: Not far at all. I just imported csv files from python to the database. And now I want to export this data from the database to json using mysql-connector

Comment: I would suggest looking over the pandas documentation on reading a SQL database, as well as dumping a dataframe to json rows

Comment: @cricket_007 I just updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `default=str` on `json.dumps` If you have objects not serializable to JSON

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM registros")
data=cursor.fetchall()
for e in data:
  print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), default=str))
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the collate for the table to utf8mb3_unicode_ci

```
alter table MyTable convert to character set utf8mb3 collate utf8mb3_unicode_ci;
```

And I used this python code to have the json result

```
@app.route("/records")
def get_records():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="me",password="xxx",database="mydb")
    cursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
    query = "SELECT * FROM records"
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result
```